# Gmail API: trouble applying auth token without user interaction

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

OS: Windows 10,
Browser: Chrome v.81,
Server: PHP 5.6,
JQuery: Version 2.1.1

Application: [Browser Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js)

The client wants this browser application to automatically renew the user's token, without forcing the user to manually re-authorize every time.

According to the quickstart page, "After the initial user authorization, calls to gapi.auth.authorize that use immediate:true mode obtain an auth token without user interaction."

I'm close to making it work. I can authorize and collect the new auth token, but I can't find the right syntax to apply that token for a renewed login sequence. Here's what I have so far.

```
    // Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state listeners.

    function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        }, function(error) {
          appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
        });
      }

    //Checks user's login state

    function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';

          //This is the API interaction I want to run.
          displayInbox();

        } else {

//I think this is where the automatic token refresh would happen (when the user
//is no longer logged in), which is why I've added in the "autoRefresh" function.

          autoRefresh();

          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

//My Auto Refresh Function, to get the new token without client interaction

    function autoRefresh() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({
          'client_id':CLIENT_ID,
          'immediate':'true',
          'scope':SCOPES
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            var access_token = response.access_token;
            console.log(access_token);

// This is where I'm stuck. I have the token, but idea how to feed it back to the 
// API, to actually renew the client's authentication.
// The only server-side example is in Python, which I can't use (client's locked into PHP).
// Before you ask, the Client's PHP server is unable to run the GMAIL API from PHP. 
// All my hopes rest on vanilla javascript... So,
// How do I authorize the client with the new access_token from here?

        });
      }

      /**
       *  These are the button functions. I've added them in just to be thorough. I'm trying 
       *  to replace the "handleAuthClick(event)" with my "autoRefresh()" function.
       */

      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }
```

As you can see, I'm close to re-authorizing the client, I just don't know the last step to submit the token back to the API server for re-authorization.

The tutorial's "authenticate" button's code (gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();) appears to require the user to manually sign in, and for the life of me and I can't find the equivalent code to authenticate to auth2 without requiring the user to sign in.

I hope this isn't too long and I'd like to thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Any help, links or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Have a great day!

Comment: Hello @SethBennett, I am not sure I understand what do you mean by "applying the token without user interaction". The user **must** authorize the respective API, and give their consent by the respective "log-in". Would you mind providing more details about your issue? Cheers!

Comment: Sure, thank you for your reply! The context is that the user has already authorized the API, but they don't want to have to re-authorize every hour or so when the API's initial login token expires. The Brower Quickstart gives  a note which suggests you can "use immediate:true mode [to] obtain an auth token without user interaction", but they don't show you how to submit that token back to the API for re-authentication. In the code above, I can get the new token, but I don't know how to submit it back to the API for re-authentication. What are your thoughts?

Comment: You might want to check this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34370927/11772035) since I think it can be of help to you. Does this answer your question? @SethBennet

Comment: This is gold! Thank you so much for pointing this out :)